# How do I can Restrict data viewing by editing the url parameter in Yii2?

Tags: parameters, get, yii2

I've an application using Yii2, basically if we want to view data, in the *view* page url exist the `id` of data.
I need to set only the owner of data can view that data, so each user can't view another user's data by editing the parameter in url.

**How do I can restrict the access? So, only who has create the data can access/view the data.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example a **user** has **rooms**,user can only edit his own rooms.
The **room model** will have a **user_id** to identify the **room owner**.
I always use this kind of trick though there might be a better way to do it
In such case you can check if the current logged in `user_id` is same as `room->user_id`

```
if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest && Yii::$app->user->identity->id == $room->user_id)
{
 //this means the user is logged in and his id is same as the $room->user_id      
 //show the edit button and other logic here
}
```

Hope it can be of help

Comment: Wow, we got the same:D I just make same condition `$model->created_id == $userId` and viewing if true, and give exception if false. Thankyou